# Load results one by one

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Good afternoon,

Currently I'm developing a web app using ASP.net Core MVC.

I would like to know if there is a way to load and show the query results one by one instead of wait until it is complete and show everything.

For example, in my application I have a query that usually returns more than 500~1,000 products. But my page stays loading until everything is completed and then display the content.

I used to develop in Clojure and there the products were loading one by one instead of waiting everything to be completed.

I am wondering if there is a way to fix this in ASP.net or maybe using AJAX.

Thank you

Comment: Load the first 50, make an ajax call with the id of last item and let the server sends the next 50 startring from the prev id. More like paging. But with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need some pagination. This way you can take only 25, or 100, or whatever number of rows you want at a time. Datatables works well for this in server side mode but it is going to take some work to setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use server side pagination, read article for this:

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part